"For" cmd in Windows recovery console
I ask if my CMD prompt in windows recovery environment can accept this kind of script, as a paste only script.
I know it works ok in the regular cmd console, but I'm not really sure about the recovery one.
I know two are in fact two kinds.
Thanx in advance
The "source" and "destination" are there only for example and not for real use.
For %F In (
  "Filename_Only1"
  "Filename_Only2"
) Do (
  XCopy "Source\%~F" "Destination" /Y /V
)

